# "Unknown task" error in Celery Flower when posting a new task

Tags: python, celery, flower

I'm running celery 3.1.11 and flower 0.6.0 .

I have a celery application configured as such;

```
# myapp.tasks.celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import    

from celery import Celery


class Config(object):
    BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'

    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = None
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
    CELERY_INCLUDE = [
        'myapp.tasks.source',
        'myapp.tasks.page',
        'myapp.tasks.diffusion',
        'myapp.tasks.place',
    ]
)

celery = Celery('myapp')
celery.config_from_object(Config)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.start()
```

I execute the celery worker using the following command:

```
$ celery -A myapp.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -E -Q celery
```

I can see the complete list of available tasks in the worker output.

```
[tasks]
  ...    
  . myapp.tasks.diffusion.post_activity
  ...
```

I then execute the flower server with the following command:

```
$ celery -A myapp.tasks flower
```

Now, whenever I try to post a new task via the Flower REST API, I get a 404 error with an error message "Unknown task TASK_NAME".

```
[W 140423 12:16:17 web:1302] 404 POST /api/task/async-apply/myapp.tasks.diffusion.post_activity (82.225.61.194): Unknown task 'myapp.tasks.diffusion.post_activity'
[W 140423 12:16:17 web:1728] 404 POST /api/task/async-apply/myapp.tasks.diffusion.post_activity (82.225.61.194) 4.68ms
```

I've put a pdb breakpoint in the flower API handler, and it appears that the only tasks available when the requests is handled are the following:

```
ipdb> pp celery.tasks
{'celery.backend_cleanup': <@task: celery.backend_cleanup of yoda.tasks.celery:0x7fb9191eb490>,
 'celery.chain': <@task: celery.chain of yoda.tasks.celery:0x7fb9191eb490>,
 'celery.chord': <@task: celery.chord of yoda.tasks.celery:0x7fb9191eb490>,
 'celery.chord_unlock': <@task: celery.chord_unlock of yoda.tasks.celery:0x7fb9191eb490>,
 'celery.chunks': <@task: celery.chunks of yoda.tasks.celery:0x7fb9191eb490>,
 'celery.group': <@task: celery.group of yoda.tasks.celery:0x7fb9191eb490>,
 'celery.map': <@task: celery.map of yoda.tasks.celery:0x7fb9191eb490>,
 'celery.starmap': <@task: celery.starmap of yoda.tasks.celery:0x7fb9191eb490>}
```

No tasks seem to be available. However, when I use the task `async_apply()` method in a shell, the task is executed by the worker.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

**Edit**: when I'm using celery 3.0.19 and flower 0.5.0, it works seemelesly.

Comment: Smells like PYTHPONPATH path to me.  Where is the module containing your tasks?  When you run the shell and do `async_apply`, are you running from your source directory?  It's possible the flower server is running with a different PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I'm running both the worker and the flower server from the same directory, which is my package root. The shell was also running in this same directory.

Comment: Can you compare the `sys.path` between your shell and the flower server by using pdb?  Perhaps check if they are different?

Comment: The only differing element is ``''``, the shell current directory. I've tried to insert it into the flower server path, at position 0, to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was due to a bug in Flower and now has been resolved:

Issue: https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/200

Resolving commit: https://github.com/mher/flower/commit/bfba1eec90124c92586c480aebaf98ae63c31276

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar problems with `flower`. My configuration was using redis.

Situation has improved at the moment I have started flower with explicit value for option "broker" (do not ask me why).

In your situation I would try

```
$ flower -r "amqp://"
```

Anyway, I would also make sure, that you start `celery` and `redis` from an environment, which has proper access to all your libraries.

Comment: I tried your idea, but I'm still getting the exact same error. I confirm that switching back to flower 0.5.0 works.