# Unknown task error in Celery 3.1.6 with flower 0.7.3

Tags: python, post, celery, flower

I'm having a similar issue to this one:
["Unknown task" error in Celery Flower when posting a new task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241431/unknown-task-error-in-celery-flower-when-posting-a-new-task)

However I'm running flower 0.7.3 which already has the fix mentioned on the previous issue. When I load flower I see the following:

```
[D 141025 19:22:44 state:87] Registered: {'celery@myhost': ['crossbar.tasks.add.add',
                             'crossbar.tasks.ping.ping',
                             'crossbar.tasks.send_email.send_email',
                             'crossbar.tasks.send_message.send_message',
                             'crossbar.tasks.send_sms.send_sms']}
[D 141025 19:22:49 events:116] Enabling events
[D 141025 19:22:50 state:153] Resuming inspecting workers...
[I 141025 19:22:50 tasks:99] Invoking a task 'crossbar.tasks.add.add' with '[1, 2]' and '{}'
[W 141025 19:22:50 web:1404] 404 POST /api/task/async-apply/crossbar.tasks.add.add (127.0.0.1): Unknown task 'crossbar.tasks.add.add'
[W 141025 19:22:50 web:1811] 404 POST /api/task/async-apply/crossbar.tasks.add.add (127.0.0.1) 1.11ms
```

But as you can see the POST fails, I'm trying to post as follows:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"args":[1,2]}' http://myhost:15629/api/task/async-apply/crossbar.tasks.add.add
```

Here is how I'm running Celery:
celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=info

And I'm running flower on a separated process like so:
flower --conf=src/crossbar/flowerconfig.py

If I replace async-apply with send-task, I get a 200 but then on the celery console I get the following error:

```
[2014-10-26 17:03:06,640: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Can't decode message body: ContentDisallowed('Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type pickle (application/x-python-serialize)',) [type:'application/x-python-serialize' encoding:'binary' headers:{}]

body: '\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x07expiresq\x02NU\x03utcq\x03\x88U\x04argsq\x04]q\x05(K\x01K\x02eU\x05chordq\x06NU\tcallbacksq\x07NU\x08errbacksq\x08NU\x07tasksetq\tNU\x02idq\nU$f1e8fc87-d0ee-4fc6-86cb-8edded4a4f4cq\x0bU\x07retriesq\x0cK\x00U\x04taskq\rX\x16\x00\x00\x00crossbar.tasks.add.addq\x0eU\ttimelimitq\x0fNN\x86q\x10U\x03etaq\x11NU\x06kwargsq\x12}q\x13u.' (229b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/psantann/Documents/git/crossbar-taskmgr_trunk/.tox/crossbar-taskmgr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 586, in _receive_callback
    decoded = None if on_m else message.decode()
  File "/Users/psantann/Documents/git/crossbar-taskmgr_trunk/.tox/crossbar-taskmgr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/message.py", line 142, in decode
    self.content_encoding, accept=self.accept)
  File "/Users/psantann/Documents/git/crossbar-taskmgr_trunk/.tox/crossbar-taskmgr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 174, in loads
    raise self._for_untrusted_content(content_type, 'untrusted')
ContentDisallowed: Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type pickle (application/x-python-serialize)
```

Ok, I don't get a serialization error anymore if I add 'pickle' to the list of accepted contents. However flower still does not know about my tasks hence async-apply does not work. I could not get flower -A app to work for me because I'm not initializing it via a celery app but rather using flowerconfig.py, in flowerconfig.py I have CELERY_IMPORTS setup but the actual tasks come from a different python package. What would be the proper way to register those with flower?

Comment: The "disallow" issue I got fixed by adding 'pickle' to the list of accept contents (yeah I know it is considered a security issue but until I figure how to have flower serialize differently that will suffice), so it seems now my only problem is getting async-apply to work.

Comment: have you setCELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER, CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER to 'json'?

Comment: Yes I did but it looks like what I was getting from flower needed 'pickle' (see my comment above). My issue right now seems related to flower (not celery) not registering my tasks. I tried to use flower -A but I don't have an celery entry point in the flower app. I was hoping I could do something equivalent from flowerconfig.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not passing `app` argument to flower. To start flower you need to invoke it with

```
flower -A your_app
```

or

```
celery flower -A your_app
```

If you don't pass `app` argument it throws a 404 error.

Comment: I'm using a somewhat different mechanism to register my tasks. A different process runs celery -A my_app and register the tasks with celery. When I run the flower command it seems to have access to the tasks since they show up in the output above.

Comment: Added some more details on how I'm running the cmds to the description

Comment: This solution actually work once I properly import my tasks, thanks Chillar